# How to resolve sorting comparison issues between two many to many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, plsql

So I have this query that compares software versions from one table (VIEW_ALL_FILES) against a master reference table (SRV_MASTER_VERSION_LIST) and some logic to flag if the match is good or bad. I'm only comparing on the software name (SRV_CMBNAME).

The issue I'm having is that while the comparison appears to work in some cases there are instances where it is not due to juxtaposition of the SRV_CURRENTVERSION and SRV_CMBRECOMMENDEDREVERSION column (see image).

```
SELECT VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBNAME,
VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBPRODVERSION AS SRV_CURRENTVERSION,
SRV_MASTER_VERSION_LIST.SRV_UPDATEDVERSION AS SRV_CMBRECOMMENDEDVERSION,
IIf([SRV_CMBPRODVERSION]=[SRV_UPDATEDVERSION],'Current','Requires Update') AS SRV_CMBVERSIONVALIDATIONFLAG,
VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBRELEASE,
VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBPUBLISHER,
VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBINSTALLDATE,
VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBDATATYPE,
IIf([SRV_CMBRELEASE]=[SRV_UPDATEDVERSION],'Current','Requires Update') AS SRV_CMBRELEASEVALIDATIONFLAG
FROM VIEW_ALL_FILES LEFT JOIN SRV_MASTER_VERSION_LIST
ON VIEW_ALL_FILES.SRV_CMBNAME = SRV_MASTER_VERSION_LIST.SRV_CMBNAME
WHERE SRV_CMBDATATYPE = 'Software'
AND SRV_CMBPRODVERSION != ''
AND SRV_UPDATEDVERSION IS NOT NULL
AND SRV_CMBDN = 'hamburgerlane1'
GO
```

I'm not sure where to tackle this (sort, top?) from where the joins occur. The challenge here is that I have a many to many relationships on the software name and versions between both tables.

[image: Data sort causing fault in validation flag comparison]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding an additional key to search on. Nulls were generated were matches don't add up.